# Amazon EC2 - Windows 2008R2 instance not reachable

Tags: windows, networking, amazon-ec2, jetty

I just set up my first Amazon EC2 instance (Windows 2008 R2 server) and istalled a jetty 9 on it. But i can not reach it with it's public IP (as shown on the desktop of that system) on port 8080.

I can reach: "http:// localhost:8080"

But i can not reach: "http:// publicIP:8080"

I allowed the port in the EC2 Security group. See the screenshot:
[image: security groupds]

I can even ping the "publicIp" from outside, but can not reach the jetty on port 8080.

I'm not sure where the problem is: Is it a configuration in windows, jetty or the EC2 Management console?

Comment: Did you check the Windows firewall?

Comment: You were right! Sometimes the most obvious things are the solution. I thougt the HTTP port is always open in the firewall :) But how can i mark this question now as solved as you just posted your answer as comment?

Comment: Added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the port is open in the Windows firewall.

Comment: You were right! Sometimes the most obvious things are the solution. I thougt the HTTP port is always open in the firewall :)

Answer (score 1):

First obvious problem might be that your security group isn't assigned to that instance.  Check that this one is the group your instance is using on the dashboard.

Comment: I also thought of that first. But it is the assigned group.